# Having a continuously updating website as a part of Windows 10 desktop so it can't be minimized

Tags: windows-10, widget

I'm looking for software to stick the contents of a continuously updating website on the Windows 10 desktop so it can't be minimized. Specifically, there's a site with a bus timetable, and I'd like it to be a part of the desktop. Something like in the picture. There's at least one tool that modifies the actual background bitmap, but it doesn't handle websites. Also, you can't just scrape the site contents and use a widget to show them (at least I don't know a way).

The software should cost a maximum of $30-$40.

Website: https://omatpysakit.foli.fi/?stops=T41&bundle=0&pagerows=16

[image: A continuously updating website as a part of the desktop]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As we recommend *software* here (not approaches), I've slightly modified your question to avoid it being closed. Could you please state whether the software should be [tag:gratis] – or how much money you'd be willing to spend if needed?